# Script does not jump to the next field when the maxlength is reached

Tags: javascript

This is my script

```
<script>
    var InputContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("InputContainer")[0];
    container.onkeyup = function(e) {
        var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
        var maxLength = parseInt(target.attributes["maxlength"].value, 10);
        var myLength = target.value.length;
        if (myLength >= maxLength) {
            var next = target;
            while (next = next.nextElementSibling) {
                if (next == null)
                    break;
                if (next.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input") {
                    next.focus();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // Move to previous field if empty (user pressed backspace)
        else if (myLength === 0) {
            var previous = target;
            while (previous = previous.previousElementSibling) {
                if (previous == null)
                    break;
                if (previous.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input") {
                    previous.focus();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have also put a  around the entire form.

You can find the original webpage at: https://im-here.biz/ContactForm/contact-inc.php

Obviously, I am doing something wrong here.

Ideas?

Comment: Where is `container` defined? Are you getting any errors in console?

Answer (score 0):

I can see an error in the console on the above-mentioned URL. By seeing your code there is no container defined. I guess you should be using **InputContainer** instead of the container variable or change the declaration like this:

```
<script defer>
 // Put your code here
  var container = document.getElementsByClassName("InputContainer")[0];
</script>
```

Comment: But I have <div class="InputContainer"> before the <form> and after as well.

Comment: How do i get to the console to see for myself?

Comment: The Web developer Tools shows it there as well. I do not see any errors in the console. When I bring my mouse over the InputContainer entry in the web console, it highlights my entire form on the page.

Comment: OK, I just saw "Uncaught TypeError: InputContainer is undefined". How do I fix this?

Comment: I think the script is loading before the html code so either use defer attribute in your script tag else move down the script to the end of the file. I have changed the sample code above.

Comment: Does anybody have a fix to my problem?

Comment: @JustAsIAm did you try defer attribute